# How to force vimtex to display \textbf and \textit in insert/normal mode?

Tags: filetype-tex, conceal, plugin-vimtex, iterm2

When I add `\textbf{}` or `\textit{}` before a word in `vimtex` the terminal shows the word but strangely hides the commands. I can only see them in the visual mode (see pictures below). Is there a way to force vim to always show `\emph{}` before the text?

I'm using Vim 8.1 on iTerm2 with the gruvbox theme if that's helpful.

[image: This is what vimtex shows in insert/normal mode]

[image: This is what I see in visual mode]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not due to `vimtex` directly, but due to the conceal feature in Vim. `vimtex` only adds to the syntax plugin that ships with Vim/neovim, and it adhers to the relevant option, see `:help g:tex_conceal`.

For direct control of the conceal feature itself, see `:help conceallevel`, `:help concealcursor` and `:help syn-conceal`.

---

Short answer, you can put the following in your vimrc file:

```
" To prevent conceal in LaTeX files
let g:tex_conceal = ''

" To prevent conceal in any file
set conceallevel = 0
```

Comment: Many thanks, Karl! Congratulations for the great plugin and thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 2):

I think would be useful a "Toggle" mapping that allows us to swich concealling level:

```
nnoremap <Leader>c :let &cole=(&cole == 2) ? 0 : 2 <bar> echo 'conceallevel ' . &cole <CR>
```